# Android: RingtoneManager not set the default ringtone

Tags: android, uri, ringtone, ringtonemanager

I am trying to change the default ringtone by programmatically. From a search I am getting the code like

```
  RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                mContext,
                RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                Uri.parse(uri));
```

But when I try to change the default ringtone it's not changing in my phone.

Where am wrong?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint here and stepped through the code? And what is the uri you are referencing?

Comment: uri represent the path for song @inner_class7

Comment: I understand its a path for the song, but what is it? have you made sure its a valid Uri is more of what I am asking? because as it stands, the code you have isn't wrong, so i am guessing it isn't a valid uri.

Comment: by using this uri i can play the song @ inner_class7

Comment: And how do you play the the song ?

Comment: just set the source for MediaPlayer and start it @ inner_class7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154361/discussion-between-inner-class7-and-binil-surendran).